# How to integrate Android App to Identity Server with ASP.NET Core 3.1 for Authentication?

Tags: android, asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, access-token

I have created ASP.NET Core project with Angular Template with authentication using visual studio. Now I am developing Android App and want to integrate it with my existing ASP.NET CORE 3.1 WEB API (Backend).
I have added client in appsettings.json for my android app as follow:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
       "MyAngularApp": {
           "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
       },
       "MyMobileApp": {
           "Profile": "NativeApp"
       }
    }
}
```

When I call my configuration endpoint "https://localhost:4042/_configuration/MyMobileApp", I got the following response;

```
{"authority":"https://localhost:4042","client_id":"MyMobileApp","redirect_uri":"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","post_logout_redirect_uri":"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","response_type":"code","scope":"offline_access MyAppAPI openid profile"}
```

I have the following Question;

- what does "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" means in the redirect_uri?
- When I added redirect_uri in client settings like this,

  "MyMobileApp": {"Profile": "NativeApp","RedirectUri": "com.example.myapplication"}

  but I didn't get my defined redirect_uri when I call the endpoint
  "https://localhost:4042/_configuration/MyMobileApp", In response I got this
  "redirect_uri":"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob". So, how can I change the default RedirectUri?

I am using AppAuth library in Android for integrating with Identity Server.

Answer (score 0):

In appsetting.json try you have to IdentityServer - Clients try this may be your issue will be resolve

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "IssuerUri": "urn:sso.company.com",
  "Clients": [
    {
      "Enabled": true,
      "ClientId": "local-dev",
      "ClientName": "Local Development",
      "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "<Insert Sha256 hash of the secret encoded as Base64 string>" } ],
      "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "implicit" ],
      "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile" ],
      "RedirectUris": [ "https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" ],
      "RequireConsent": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When using this client configuration, I got compile time error 
" System.InvalidOperationException: 'Type '' is not supported.' This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureClients.GetClients()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureClients.Configure(Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ApiAuthorizationOptions)
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<TOptions>.Create(string) ... ".